# Having trouble understanding Linked-List in C/C++

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Hello I am a newbie in data structures. So I am learning linked lists. The main problem for me is that different people code differently in tutorials making me more confused. So here are two codes.
The first one is:

```
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};

int main() {
  struct node *head,*current;

  head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  head->data = 10;
  head->next = NULL;

  current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  current->data = 20;
  current->next = NULL;
  head->next = current;

  current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  current->data = 50;
  current->next = NULL;
  head->next->next->next->next = current;

  struct node* temp = head;
  while(temp != NULL) {
   printf("%d ",temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
```

I understood everything but here my question is how `head->next = current` works?? I mean `current->next` always remain NULL, right? The `head` moves to `current` then how is the `head` maintained?
Now here is the alternative code of the above just to avoid writing `head->next->next->next` many times.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *current = NULL;

    head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data = 10;
    head->next = NULL;

    current = head;

    current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current = current->next;
    current->data = 20;
    current->next = NULL;

    current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current = current->next;
    current->data = 50;
    current->next = NULL;

    struct node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

Here in the second code i literally don't understand anything. Here `current = head` that means pointing `current` to the first element. Then why `current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node))` instead of `current = malloc(sizeof(struct node))`? And then how do they use `current->data` when they didnt use `current = malloc(sizeof(struct node))` ? And why `current =  current->next` ? It would be better if you explain verbosely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing *what* these are supposed to do, it is difficult to explain *why* or *how* this particular code was used.

Comment: `head->next->next->next->next = current;` in the first example is wrong. `head->next->next` is `NULL`, dereferencing this will crash

Answer (score 1):

i think you missing the basics of linked-list. I'm sure that you know that linked list mean bunch of data or elements are linked together. but how they are linked and how to process them or create them, you need to learn more about those skills.
I'm posting few links where you can learn more about those techniques in visual way,[visual tutorial link](https://t4tutorials.com/link-list/), [PPT tutorial link](https://www.slideshare.net/PratikNaik41/what-is-link-list-explained-with-animations).
now to your code:

```
struct node *head,*current;
```

You need 2 nodes, the head of your linked list and this one should never change unless you have empty linked list or for a specific task, think of the head as the only clue you have to start looping inside your linked list, like the key of your house, you never miss it or throw it, always keep it safe.
current is the node you will create and add it to the linked list, and since linked list uses variable address, when you save the address of the new node you just create it, you can use the current variable again to create new node. and this explain the next piece of code:

```
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->data = 10;
head->next = NULL;
```

head is empty and you need to add a new node, so you use malloc to allocate the memory space and then add the variable you want (10 here) and since this is the only node, so there is no next node (NULL here). to apply what i said before about using current, you can use current instead of head, and at the end you just add head = current (again, head changed because it was empty).
in your next instructions you will keep using current to create new node, like this:

```
current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
current->data = 20;
current->next = NULL;
```

and since all node are linked together, the last node will point to the new node you want to add using (next). head was the first and the only node in your linked list, when you added new node, you need save its address in your linked list like this:

```
head->next = current;
```

now, if you have more node and you need to add them to your list, you need to use the same technic, head->next->...->next = current (the number of next is limited to the number of elements or nodes in your linked list.
you can't keep using head->next->...->next every time you want to add element, so you use current to heal you to reach the last element in your linked list (don't use head, because you don't want to change is value, again, it's the key of your house) and use another variable of type node lets call it newNode, with newNode you create a new node or element, and add it to the end of your list like this:

```
current->next = newNode;
```

current is the last element in your linked list, to reach the last element, use while like this:

```
current = head; // this is the start point to avoid losing head
while(current->next != null){
 current = current->next;
}
```

now about the second half of your question:

> why current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node)) instead of current = malloc(sizeof(struct node))

in the code you have current = head;
and your linst is not empty, only one element is there, and you want to add element in the end of your list, so he directly created node inside the current->next (or header->next) because remember, in linked list we work with pointers, so next is the pointer to the next element, and he just rush it and reserve a memory space for the new element, then he changed current from header to the new element address using "current = current->next;" and give that new node a value (20) and since it's the last in the least, it's next is null.
if he didn't use "current = current->next;" then he need to use current->next->data = 20 and current->next->next = null" , i think this is not a good looking instruction.

one recommendation, don't do things like this code, always use function to add, remove, replace, sort a linked list, it's better looking, organized and will save you header.
best regards

Answer (score 1):

It may help to visualise what happens after each statement:

```
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *current = NULL;
```

Two variables are declared, which are pointers initialised with `NULL`:

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─current─┐
│ NULL │   │  NULL   │
└──────┘   └─────────┘
```

```
    head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Now we have a node, and `head` points to it:

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─current─┐
│  ┬   │   │  NULL   │
└──│───┘   └─────────┘
   │
   │
   │   ┌─data─┐
   │   │  ?   │
   └──►├─next─┤
       │  ?   │
       └──────┘
```

The members of this node have undefined values; they get initialised:

```
    head->data = 10;
    head->next = NULL;
```

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─current─┐
│  ┬   │   │  NULL   │
└──│───┘   └─────────┘
   │
   │
   │   ┌─data─┐
   │   │  10  │
   └──►├─next─┤
       │ NULL │
       └──────┘
```

Following that, `current` will be assigned the same pointer as `head` has:

```
    current = head;
```

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─current─┐
│  ┬   │   │    ┬    │
└──│───┘   └────│────┘
   │ ┌──────────┘
   │ │
   │ │ ┌─data─┐
   │ └►│  10  │
   └──►├─next─┤
       │ NULL │
       └──────┘
```

The second node is created and a pointer to it is assigned to the `next` field of the first node:

```
    current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─current─┐
│  ┬   │   │    ┬    │
└──│───┘   └────│────┘
   │ ┌──────────┘
   │ │
   │ │ ┌─data─┐   ┌─data─┐
   │ └►│  10  │   │  ?   │
   └──►├─next─┤   ├─next─┤
       │   ──────►│  ?   │
       └──────┘   └──────┘
```

Then we update `current` to point to that new node:

```
    current = current->next;
```

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─current─┐
│  ┬   │   │    ┬    │
└──│───┘   └────│────┘
   │            │
   │            │
   │   ┌─data─┐ │ ┌─data─┐
   │   │  10  │ └►│  ?   │
   └──►├─next─┤   ├─next─┤
       │   ──────►│  ?   │
       └──────┘   └──────┘
```

And again the node's fields are initialised:

```
    current->data = 20;
    current->next = NULL;
```

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─current─┐
│  ┬   │   │    ┬    │
└──│───┘   └────│────┘
   │            │
   │            │
   │   ┌─data─┐ │ ┌─data─┐
   │   │  10  │ └►│  20  │
   └──►├─next─┤   ├─next─┤
       │   ──────►│ NULL │
       └──────┘   └──────┘
```

The whole process repeats for the third node, so that after this block of code:

```
    current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current = current->next;
    current->data = 50;
    current->next = NULL;
```

...we get:

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─current─┐
│  ┬   │   │    ┬    │
└──│───┘   └────│────┘
   │            └──────────┐
   │                       │
   │   ┌─data─┐   ┌─data─┐ │ ┌─data─┐
   │   │  10  │   │  20  │ └►│  50  │
   └──►├─next─┤   ├─next─┤   ├─next─┤
       │   ──────►│   ──────►│ NULL │
       └──────┘   └──────┘   └──────┘
```

Here the population of the linked list ends. `current` is no more used, and instead a new variable `temp` is introduced. It gets initialised with the same pointer that `head` has:

```
    struct node *temp = head;
```

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─temp─┐
│  ┬   │   │  ┬   │
└──│───┘   └──│───┘
   │ ┌────────┘
   │ │
   │ │ ┌─data─┐   ┌─data─┐   ┌─data─┐
   │ └►│  10  │   │  20  │   │  50  │
   └──►├─next─┤   ├─next─┤   ├─next─┤
       │   ──────►│   ──────►│ NULL │
       └──────┘   └──────┘   └──────┘
```

The first iteration of the loop will print `temp->data`, i.e. 10. Then with `temp = temp->next` the pointer at `temp` points to the second node:

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─temp─┐
│  ┬   │   │  ┬   │
└──│───┘   └──│───┘
   │          └─┐
   │            │
   │   ┌─data─┐ │ ┌─data─┐   ┌─data─┐
   │   │  10  │ └►│  20  │   │  50  │
   └──►├─next─┤   ├─next─┤   ├─next─┤
       │   ──────►│   ──────►│ NULL │
       └──────┘   └──────┘   └──────┘
```

And so the second iteration of the loop will print 20. Similarly the third iteration of the loop will start in this state:

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─temp─┐
│  ┬   │   │  ┬   │
└──│───┘   └──│───┘
   │          └────────────┐
   │                       │
   │   ┌─data─┐   ┌─data─┐ │ ┌─data─┐
   │   │  10  │   │  20  │ └►│  50  │
   └──►├─next─┤   ├─next─┤   ├─next─┤
       │   ──────►│   ──────►│ NULL │
       └──────┘   └──────┘   └──────┘
```

And when `temp = temp->next` is executed, `temp` gets the value `NULL`:

```
┌─head─┐   ┌─temp─┐
│  ┬   │   │ NULL │
└──│───┘   └──────┘
   │
   │
   │   ┌─data─┐   ┌─data─┐   ┌─data─┐
   │   │  10  │   │  20  │   │  50  │
   └──►├─next─┤   ├─next─┤   ├─next─┤
       │   ──────►│   ──────►│ NULL │
       └──────┘   └──────┘   └──────┘
```

The loop condition is now false and the program ends.

Hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:
Allocate 1st node and point head and current to 1st node:

```
    head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data = 10;
    head->next = NULL;
    current = head;
```

Set 1st node next pointer to 2nd allocated node

```
    current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Advance current to 2nd node and set data

```
    current = current->next;
    current->data = 20;
    current->next = NULL;
```

Set 2nd node next pointer to 3rd allocated node

```
    current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Advance current to 3rd node and set data

```
    current = current->next;
    current->data = 50;
    current->next = NULL;
```

Display the 3 nodes

```
    struct node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### about the 1st example

> I understood everything but here my question is how head->next = current works?

If you understood everything on the 1st example then you know it is wrong.

`head->next` is just a pointer:

```
  struct node* next;
```

So `*next` is `struct node`, this is the meaning of the `*` here in `C`: *de-reference* the pointer.

`head->next` just points to the second node.

It can not exist: a linked list can have one node, can be empty...

So the funny line

```
  head->next->next->next->next = current;
```

makes the 5th element of the list point to whatever `current` points to. Just follow the links...

This makes no sense, probably will corrupt the list's links. And sure will crash the program if the list has less than 5 nodes. Thing again: any of this `next` pointers can be `NULL`.

changing this line to

```
  head->next->next = current;
```

makes the code work.

But consider that

- in linked lists we almost never navigate beyond the next or previous link. It obviously will crash if we have only one node...

Also

- lists with links in only one direction are in fact more complicated to navigate then lists with pointers back and forward. When navigating many times we need to go in the other direction, and with no links we need to save more and more pointers in code.
- lists are abstractions. Consider a playlist, a queue: when deleting a song from the middle of the list with pointers only forward, like your `next` case, we do not have a clue about the previous song, but we know that somewhere in the memory there is a node that points to the song we are now deleting. So to be able to delete a song we need to save the address of the previous one, so when we find the node for the song we are about to delete we can make the previous one point to the one after the one we are deleting, before deleting the node with the song

### about the 2nd example

The code here is ok.

- it never tries to access beyond he next link, and it works.
- it initializes the pointers on declaration, good practice

### a 3rd way: a better abstraction

From the 2 examples:

````
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};

int main() {
  struct node *head,*current;```

```C
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *current = NULL;
````

We have not even a list. just a single `struct` for a *node* and 2 global pointers.

How about the list? how many elements in the list? Not even this simple value is there. A loop is needed every time we need to know the size.

linked lists are data structures, like queues, sets, stacks, maps and arrays. Linked lists are *containers* of things. `C++` even call these structures *containers*. *java*  calls it *Collections*.

linked lists are possibly empty collection of nodes. The nodes points to or contain one record of data, and the links.

#### a `List` before all

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    Node*  head;
    Node*  tail;
} List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes
```

Now we have a list. And each list has a `head` node, a `tail` node and a `size`.

We can declare things like

```
    List a_1000 = List[1000];
```

And have an array of 1,000 lists. Each one has its size and head. Inside. This is called *encapsulation*  and is a powerful concept: it lets the code see a `List` as an object, a class, and use it as an unit.

#### what is a node for a list

A list is just a list. It should not make difference what the list is, well, listing. A node could be

```
typedef struct st_node
{
    struct node* next;
    int          data;
} Node;
```

as here, but could also be

```
typedef struct st_node
{
    struct node* next;
    void*        info;
} Node;
```

and point to an arbitrary thing. This is *polymorphism*, since it can be anything: the power of `void` ;)

#### use operations on `List`

Since we now have a list we can think of operations on lists, monolithic things that are harder to fail and easier to test. These *operations* could follow a principle, the **SRP**, Single Responsibility Principle, and life gets easier.

### an example

#### creating and destroying such a `List`

It is better to see these operations are pairs, so

```
List* ls_create()
{
    List* list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
}

List* ls_destroy(List* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;  // no list
    for (size_t i = 0; i < del->size; i += 1)
    {  // delete nodes, 1 by 1
        Node* save = del->head->next;
        free(del->head);
        del->head = save;
    };
    free(del);  // delete list
    fprintf(stderr, "list destroyed\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

And a simple program like this already works:

```
int main(void)
{
    List*        one = ls_create();
    printf("  %llu elements on list\n", one->size);
    one = ls_destroy(one);
    return 0;
}
```

and shows

```
list created
  0 elements on list
list destroyed
```

It is good for moral support.

#### printing

This is not a common operation for a list, but is a mandatory one for testing. Since it must work even if the list is empty (or the pointer is invalid) is the next one to write.

A simple one:

```
    int ls_print(List* list, const char* msg);
```

It is useful to accept an optional message: it avoids most of the countless `printf` in testing. A possible implementation is in the code below

#### inserting at both ends

```
int   ls_push_back(int item, List* list);
int   ls_push_front(int item, List* list);
```

These use names common in other languages, The use is obvious. Code is in the example, but anyway this is the most common one: insert at the end:

```
// inserts 'item' at the tail of the list
int ls_push_back(int item, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->data = item;
    if (list->size == 0)  // first node
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->next       = NULL;
    list->tail->next = node;
    list->tail       = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}
```

#### a new example

Now we can run code like

```
int main(void)
{
    List* one = ls_create();
    ls_print(one, "still empty");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) ls_push_back(i, one);
    ls_print(one, "\ninserted 0,1,2 at back\n");
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i += 1) ls_push_front(i, one);
    ls_print(one, "\ninserted 3,4,5 at front\n");
    one = ls_destroy(one);
    return 0;
}
```

and see

```
list created
still empty List is empty
inserted 0,1,2 at back
    #3 elements in list.
    head element: 0
    tail element: 2
0  1  2
[-----]


inserted 3,4,5 at front
    #6 elements in list.
    head element: 5
    tail element: 2
5  4  3  0  1  2
[-----]

list destroyed
```

#### a practical helper for testing

Consider

```
int ls_multi_insert(
    List* list, const unsigned N, ...)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        ls_push_back(va_arg(args, int), list);
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}
```

and **this program does the same as the 2 examples at que question**

```
int main(void)
{
    List* one = ls_create();
    ls_print(one, "still empty:");
    ls_multi_insert(one, 3, 10, 20, 50);
    ls_print(one, "\ninserted 10,20,50 at back\n");
    one = ls_destroy(one);
    return 0;
}
```

```
list created
still empty: List is empty
inserted 10,20,50 at back
    #3 elements in list.
    head element: 10
    tail element: 50
10  20  50
[-----]

list destroyed
```

#### complete code of the example

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct st_node
{
    int             data;
    struct st_node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    Node*  head;
    Node*  tail;
} List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes

List* ls_create();
List* ls_destroy(List*);
int   ls_multi_insert(List* list, const unsigned N, ...);
int   ls_print(List* list, const char* msg);
int   ls_push_back(int item, List* list);
int   ls_push_front(int item, List* list);

int main(void)
{
    List* one = ls_create();
    ls_print(one, "still empty:");
    ls_multi_insert(one, 3, 10, 20, 50);
    ls_print(one, "\ninserted 10,20,50 at back\n");
    one = ls_destroy(one);
    return 0;
}

List* ls_create()
{
    List* list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "list created\n");
    return list;
}

List* ls_destroy(List* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;  // no list
    for (size_t i = 0; i < del->size; i += 1)
    {  // delete nodes, 1 by 1
        Node* save = (Node*)del->head->next;
        free(del->head);
        del->head = save;
    };
    free(del);  // delete list
    fprintf(stderr, "list destroyed\n");
    return NULL;
}

int ls_multi_insert(List* list, const unsigned N, ...)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        ls_push_back(va_arg(args, int), list);
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}

int ls_print(List* list, const char* msg)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No valid list!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        if (msg != NULL)
            printf("%s List is empty", msg);
        else
            printf("list is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "\
    #%llu elements in list.\n\
    head element: %d\n\
    tail element: %d\n",
        list->size, list->head->data, list->tail->data);
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%d  ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n[-----]\n\n");
    return 0;
}

// inserts 'item' at the tail of the list
int ls_push_back(int item, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->data = item;
    if (list->size == 0)  // first node
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->next       = NULL;
    list->tail->next = node;
    list->tail       = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

// inserts 'Item' at the head of the list
int ls_push_front(int item, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->data = item;
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->next = list->head;
    list->head = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}
```